# Primefaces Growl Messaging Duplicate overlays

Tags: primefaces

When I use the Primefaces growl control I'm able to get duplicate overlays to appear if I click the below button more than once back to back.  The next set appears before the first set fades. Is there any way to not show the overlays until the first set fade?

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" life="3000" errorIcon="/images/Validation-Error.png" infoIcon="/images/Validation-Success.png"/> 

<p:commandButton styleClass="form-btn2"
        value="#{bundle['signUp.button.LABEL']}" actionListener="#{signUpDetail.signUp}" onclick="signUpDlg.show();trackingSignUpOverlaySave()" 
        oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" update="growl"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected, same request, same response, same overlay.